# How can i find a string in a txt file and linenumber

Tags: vb.net

I would like to make a "Tolerance-calculator"

The user gives an input as string. For example:"D6" now i have to search this in the .txt file and read the next line.

[image: Picture_txt_with_string_and_tolerances]

I read the file like this:

```
Dim Findstring = IO.File.ReadAllText("....\Toleranz0.txt")
```

How can i find the string an the next line after the string?

Maybe:

```
Findstring.contains("D6") 'gives a Boolean
```

How does i get the correct line?

Comment: Try `ReadAllLines` instead. That gives you an array of strings, one for each line. Then you can use `Array.IndexOf` to find the line number of the input.

Comment: @Bek ...or read one line twice (till the end of file) and make a dictionary out of it.

Comment: try the following:

split to split the text. This also has the good point that what happens if there are more than D6 characters.

2.- the following line is the line contained between '\n' and '\n'

Comment: `Regex.Match(input, "(?<=D6\r?\n).*").Value` will return the next line.  If you want all of them, you can loop through the collection returned by `Matches` instead of calling `Match`, which just returns the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your string to an array using `String.Split()` and find the next index or 2 indexes after "D6":

```
Private Sub Funcy()
    Dim Findstring As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("....\Toleranz0.txt")
    Dim MyCollection() As String = Findstring.Split()
    Dim result As String = MyCollection(Array.IndexOf(MyCollection, "D6") + 2)
    MessageBox.Show(result)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `ReadAllLines()` as suggested by Blorgbeard:

```
Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("....\Toleranz0.txt")
Dim index As Integer = Array.IndexOf(lines, "D6")
If index <> -1 AndAlso index <= lines.Count - 2 Then
    Dim targetLine As String = lines(index + 1)
    ' ... do something with "targetLine" ...
Else
    ' either the line was not found, or there was no line after the found line
End If
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help :-)